# Write a function in scheme (racket) to return a list of odd integers in a given range

Tags: scheme, racket

Here is what I have written:

```
(define (odd-interval low high)
  (cond
    ((and (eqv? low high) (not(eqv?(modulo high 2) 0))) high)
    ((eqv? low high) '())
    ((not(eqv? (modulo low 2) 0)) (cons low (odd-interval (+ low 1) high)))
    (else (odd-interval(+ low 1) high))
    )
  )
```

This is how I am calling odd-interval:

```
(odd-interval '1 '9 )
```

But this is the output:

```
(1 3 5 7 . 9)
```

Can someone please help me figure out where the period is coming from in the output? It's not there if I have an even number for high.

For example, the following call for odd-interval:

```
(odd-interval '1 '8 )
```

will return:

```
(1 3 5 7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case:

```
((and (eqv? low high) (not(eqv?(modulo high 2) 0))) high)
```

Should have `(list high)` instead of `high`

In the other cases value is either a `cons`, or `'()`, or the value of an expression that results in either of these. This case is neither. Its value is high which is a number. The apparent fix is to wrap the number in a list so that other items may be consed to that list.

Answer (score 3):

**Use appropriate comparison operators**

In general, to compare elements in scheme the suggestion is to use the more “specialized” operator available. For numbers, the equality operator to use is `=`, not `eqv?`.

**Check your input parameters**

If the function is called with `(odd-interval 3 2)` the function loops forever. So the termination test should be `(> low high)` or `(>= low high)`, and not `(= low high)` or `(eqv? low high)`.

**Use primitive functions when available**

`odd?` is already available to test if a number is odd.

So the function could be rewritten as:

```
(define (odd-interval low high)
  (cond ((> low high) '())
        ((odd? low) (cons low (odd-interval (+ low 1) high)))
        (else (odd-interval (+ low 1) high))))
```

Note: you can use `>=` instead of `>` if the range excludes the last element, which is very frequently requested.

Finally, note that numbers are evaluates to themselves, there is no need to quote them, so instead of:

```
(odd-interval '1 '9)
```

the usual way is to write:

```
(odd-interval 1 9)
```

Comment: You brought up some things i didn't consider. Thanks for taking the time to help me out!